# Displaying textarea content on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a text area and a button.Like this :

```
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="add text" id="add" />
```

Now,what i want to do is that on click of the button that text to be displayed on the same page above this text area just like we do comment or answer a question on stackoverflow.

How this can be done ?Please help.

Comment: Please try something before asking other dude to code it for you. Why don't you read some basic tutos?!

Comment: yea dude atleast do the click handler [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: @A.Wolff I had basic knowledge but here in this case i dont know were to get started.

Comment: Try not to post code based questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using javascript
add any tag before (generally div or span tag is used) textarea tag

```
<div id="adduserdata"></div>
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="add text" id="add" onclick="showtext()" />
```

Javascript code would be

```
function showtext(){
 var text = document.getElementById("txtarea");
 var showarea = document.getElementById("adduserdata");
 showarea.innerHTML=text.value;
}
```

[here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mauryaashish945/qvT3V/)

Comment: But the problem is as soon as i press the button and type again the previous values are gone.So i dont want them to go.

Comment: i have added the working example link <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/mauryaashish945/qvT3V/">here is example</a>

Comment: I know to do that.The problem is that the previous enetered text should also stay

Comment: if you want to append data simply change"showarea.innerHTML=text.value"  to "showarea.innerHTML+=text.value"

Answer (score 0):

This will do if using Jquery (and previously text will stay) :

```
$('.button').click(function(){
var text = $('textarea').val();
if(text!=''){
$('p').text(text);
}
});
```

or like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
var text = $('textarea').val();
if(text!=''){
$('<p></p>').text(text).insertBefore('textarea');
}
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59g3g/)

Comment: This is not want is being asked in question.Please

Comment: He asked :"text to be displayed on the same page above text area"... I think that my answer does what he wanted...

Answer (score 0):

As what you want, thus appending to the `<div>` division element, I assume that you will accept this answer (as a summary to all the comments and answers above) :

```
<!-- This is the HTML Part -->
<div id="text"></div>
<textarea id="new"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="appendTextToDiv();" />
<script>
    function appendTextToDiv(){document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = document.getElmentById("text").innerHTML + document.getElementById("new").value;}
</script>
```

This can let you simply append it to the text. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WKfj/)